# Broadcast join in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I'm joining two dataframes `df1`(15k rows) and `df2`(with 6 million rows). I have broadcasted `df1` and reparationed `df2` to 20.

And `spark.sql.shuffle.partition` is by default set to 200.
Now when joining these two DF, data is again getting shuffled and I can see 200 tasks are spawned with only 4 partition having data.

Ideally there's no shuffling involved as I have broadcasted small DF. But still join is resulting into 200 tasks with uneven records. I expecting it should not repartition data as I have already broadcasted table. As I can see in explain plan SortMergeJoin is invoked.

```
def HC_LE_BM(BM, HC_LE):
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin','False')
print(spark.conf.get('spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin'))
df1 = HC_LE
df2 = BM
df2 = df2.repartition(20).cache()
print("Print partition", df2.rdd.getNumPartitions())
print("Storage level", df2.storageLevel)
BENCH_HEIGHT_OFFSET = 25
df3 = df2.join(F.broadcast(df1), (
                    (df1.SRC_DIG_X >= df2.min_x) &
                    (df1.SRC_DIG_X < df2.max_x) &
                    (df1.SRC_DIG_Y >= df2.min_y) &
                    (df1.SRC_DIG_Y < df2.max_y) &
                    (df1.SRC_DIG_Z <= df2.min_z) &
                    ((df1.SRC_DIG_Z + BENCH_HEIGHT_OFFSET) >= df2.max_z) &
                    (df1.ORIGIN == df2.ORIGIN_BM)
                    ),
                how = 'right'
                )\
            .select('*')
df3.explain(True)
df3.show(truncate=False)
```

Please find attached log.

== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeJoin [ORIGIN_BM#6341], [ORIGIN#6395], RightOuter, ((((((SRC_DIG_X#6519 >= min_x#6360) && (SRC_DIG_X#6519 < max_x#6361)) && (SRC_DIG_Y#6520 >= min_y#6362)) && (SRC_DIG_Y#6520 < max_y#6363)) && (SRC_DIG_Z#6521 <= min_z#6364)) && ((SRC_DIG_Z#6521 + 25.0) >= max_z#6365))
:- *(2) Sort [ORIGIN_BM#6341 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ORIGIN_BM#6341, 200), true
:     +- *(1) Filter ((((((isnotnull(min_z#6364) && isnotnull(max_y#6363)) && isnotnull(max_x#6361)) && isnotnull(max_z#6365)) && isnotnull(min_y#6362)) && isnotnull(min_x#6360)) && isnotnull(ORIGIN_BM#6341))
:        +- InMemoryTableScan [ORIGIN_BM#6341, ORIGIN_LOCATION_BENCH_BM#6342, block_id#6343, centroid_x#6344, centroid_y#6345, centroid_z#6346, dim_x#6347, dim_y#6348, dim_z#6349, volume#6350, rktype_now#6351, rkzone_now#6352, densnow_2013#6353, category_dil#6354, class_dil#6355, btot_dil#6356, as_dil#6357, densnow_2015#6358, densnow_rma#6359, min_x#6360, max_x#6361, min_y#6362, max_y#6363, min_z#6364, max_z#6365], [isnotnull(min_z#6364), isnotnull(max_y#6363), isnotnull(max_x#6361), isnotnull(max_z#6365), isnotnull(min_y#6362), isnotnull(min_x#6360), isnotnull(ORIGIN_BM#6341)]
:              +- InMemoryRelation [ORIGIN_BM#6341, ORIGIN_LOCATION_BENCH_BM#6342, block_id#6343, centroid_x#6344, centroid_y#6345, centroid_z#6346, dim_x#6347, dim_y#6348, dim_z#6349, volume#6350, rktype_now#6351, rkzone_now#6352, densnow_2013#6353, category_dil#6354, class_dil#6355, btot_dil#6356, as_dil#6357, densnow_2015#6358, densnow_rma#6359, min_x#6360, max_x#6361, min_y#6362, max_y#6363, min_z#6364, max_z#6365], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
:                    +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(20), false
:                       +- *(1) FileScan parquet !ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000000-e6aa-5004-bd4a-ac6c2019674d:ri.foundry.main.transaction.00000000-e6aa-5004-bd4a-ac6c2019674d@00000000-4c09-7aa9-9c6c-752a1b9849cd:master.ri.foundry.main.dataset.667a9c8b-dde2-4524-acae-7f6c4183141e[ORIGIN_BM#6341,ORIGIN_LOCATION_BENCH_BM#6342,block_id#6343,centroid_x#6344,centroid_y#6345,centroid_z#6346,dim_x#6347,dim_y#6348,dim_z#6349,volume#6350,rktype_now#6351,rkzone_now#6352,densnow_2013#6353,category_dil#6354,class_dil#6355,btot_dil#6356,as_dil#6357,densnow_2015#6358,densnow_rma#6359,min_x#6360,max_x#6361,min_y#6362,max_y#6363,min_z#6364,max_z#6365] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: FoundryCatalogFileIndex[sparkfoundry://*.com/datasets/ri.foundry.main.datase..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct.com/datasets/ri.foundry.main.datase..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct

Comment: show the code please, otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: what's the size of df1 (in KB/MB)?

Comment: Any luck or suggestions?